# Remove edit option according to worklog id in JIRA

Tags: groovy, jira

In JIRA, I need to remove the option to edit or delete some of the worklogs in the activity tab panel. I used behavior for this but I couldn't make any changes in the worklog pop out window. I am using groovy with script runner.

I called the API using `import com.atlassian.jira.plugin.issuetabpanel`. The interface has `WorklogAction` class. I created a new object with this class but could not find function to use this object. Can you help with this?

Comment: How did you call the API? Do you have the correct permissions? We need a bit more info on what you tried and what failed.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I believe you know and consulted [docs.atlassian.com > WorklogAction](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/7.6.1/com/atlassian/jira/issue/tabpanels/WorklogAction.html). Please edit your question and add what other things you tried, which other resources you consulted.